# Why is hash() slower under python3.4 vs python2.7

Tags: python, python-3.4

I was doing some performance evaluation using timeit and discovered a performance degredation between python 2.7.10 and python 3.4.3. I narrowed it down to the `hash()` function:

python 2.7.10:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('for x in xrange(100): hash(x)', number=100000)
0.4529099464416504
>>> timeit.timeit('hash(1000)')
0.044638872146606445
```

python 3.4.3:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('for x in range(100): hash(x)', number=100000)
0.6459149940637872
>>> timeit.timeit('hash(1000)')
0.07708719989750534
```

That's an approx. 40% degradation! It doesn't seem to matter if integers, floats, strings(unicodes or bytearrays), etc, are being hashed; the degradation is about the same. In both cases the hash is returning a 64-bit integer. The above was run on my Mac, and got a smaller degradation (20%) on an Ubuntu box.

I've also used PYTHONHASHSEED=random for the python2.7 tests and in *some* cases, restarting python for each "case", I saw the `hash()` performance get a bit worse, but never as slow as python3.4

Anyone know what's going on here? Was a more-secure, but slower, hash function chosen for python3 ?

Comment: The hash function is definitely not secure.  It's not intended as a cryptographic hash.  It's main purpose is to be used for `dict`s and `set`s.

Comment: Sven: I understand that. Please read the first paragraph: I'm not using it for cryptographic purposes. In fact, I'm not using hash() directly at all, but this is, I believe, the underlying cause of why somedict[someindex] under python3.4 is slower than under python 2.7

Comment: They switched to SipHash in Python 3.4 which is slower than FNV on some data. See https://bugs.python.org/issue14621

Comment: @vaultah: Thank you! Throw that in as an "answer" with a reference, and I'll give you an upvote! anonymous: you notice a difference when it's run billions of times. 40% is 40%.

Comment: @ChrisCogdon I was replying to the last question.  The hash is not secure.

Comment: @vaultah The timings in the question are for hashes of integers.  They haven't changed at all in Python 3.  Each integer (except for -1) still hashes to itself.

Comment: @ChrisCogdon I believe that the difference you are seeing is because integers are slower in Python 3.  In Python 2, small integers were represented as C integers internally (called `int` in Python), and only if necessary an arbitrary-precision integer was instantiated (called `long` in Python).  This disctinction has been dropped.  The return value of the hash function needs to be wrapped in a Python objects, and this is slower than it used to be.  Try timing e.g. `id(1000)` instead, and you will see the same speed difference.

Comment: However, this difference shouldn't affect dictionary access, since for accessing a dictionary, the hash doesn't need to be wrapped in a Python `int`.  If the keys of your dictionary are strings, then indeed the change pointed out by @vaultah could be the reason.

Comment: Could not reproduce. Python **3.5.2** is *a little* slower for me: http://oi64.tinypic.com/205ch3m.jpg ... What OS/system specs?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: SipHash is secure.  It is not a cryptographic hash, however, it is a secure hash algorithm.  Security is the entire reason the algorithm was even designed in the first place.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Hashing an integer to itself is not a secure hash.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: "SipHash is secure." Talking about SipHash.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, i get that, and it's a good comment.  I'm talking about `hash()` in general, not only for strings.  (And the example timings given in the post aren't for strings.)

Answer (score 3):

There are two changes in `hash()` function between Python 2.7 and Python 3.4

1. Adoptions of *SipHash*
2. Default enabling of *Hash randomization*

---

*References:*

- Since from Python 3.4, it uses [SipHash](https://131002.net/siphash/) for it's hashing function. Read: [Python adopts SipHash](https://lwn.net/Articles/574761/)
- Since Python 3.3 *Hash randomization is enabled by default.* Reference: [`object.__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) (last line of this section). Specifying [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) the value 0 will disable hash randomization.

Comment: Hash randomization is also enabled by default in every 2.7 release since at least four years.  Moreover, this only affects string hashes, whereas the examples in the OP are hashes of integers, which are not randomized.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: "Hash randomization is also enabled by default in every 2.7 release since at least five years" - uh, what? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @user2357112 You are right, it's not enabled by default.  It's just enabled on the platforms I happen to use regularly (even for Python 2.7).  Anyway, this is still irrelevant for the timing differences observed in the original post, since hashes of integers are not randomized.

Comment: Note that hash randomization doesn't make the hashes slower.  A random seed is determined once at startup and included in the hashes.  If it is disabled, 0 is used instead.  There is no speed difference.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Agree with you. That it is not entirely due to `PYTHONHASHSEED`, updated the answer

Comment: I suggest running `python -Rc 'print(hash("a"))'` multiple times, and then `python -Rc 'print(hash(1000))'`.  You will see that the hash of `1000` is always `1000`.  Hash randomization is only for strings.  It's not only not the entire reason, it's completely immaterial for integer hashes, and even for string hashes, it doesn't result in any speed difference whatsoever.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Made an edit. Deleted the part I was not sure about. But it looks like you are right.